# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: marked

Tags: reactjs, javascript-marked

I am using React and Marked for a markdown previewer in Codepen.io. Here's a link to my project and JavaScript code:

https://codepen.io/lengvarskyj/pen/bGrrqeg

```
const initialState  = `
# Heading 1
## Heading 2
  
**This is bolded text**

[This is a link](https://www.freecodecamp.org)

This is inline code: \`<div></div>\`

> This is a code block
  
\`\`\`
  
x = y + 3
  
\`\`\`

- List item 1
- List item 2
- List item 3
  
![FreeCodeCamp](https://design-style-guide.freecodecamp.org/downloads/fcc_secondary_large.svg)
`;

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: initialState
  }
 
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState ({
      text: e.target.value
    })
  }
  
  render () {
  
  const { text } = this.state;
  const markdown = marked(text, {breaks: true});
    
    return (
    <div>
        <h2>Markdown Previewer</h2>
        <div id='areas'>
          <div id='text-area'>
          <h3>Enter Here</h3>
          <textarea id="editor" class='box' value={text} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>
          <div id='preview-area'>
          <h3>Result</h3>
          <div id='preview' class='box' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: markdown}}></div>
          </div> 
        </div>
        </div>
    );                                                        
  }
};


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I actually had this running perfectly and then all of the sudden I started getting this error message. It seems like the Markdown isn't picking up 'marked' (line 40) even though it originally was. You can delete this line to see how the project should look.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Changing your external script link for marked to `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.6/marked.min.js` made it work again

Comment: It works, thank you so much!! Is there any particular reason that this version of marked worked when others didn't?

Comment: @Lengvarskyj You have exchanged the link so I can't check the original error message anymore.
But with the current version of marked from npm which you were trying to use the export is an object and not a function. So instead of marked() you might just had to use marked.parse() . Also after some trying, I found that when using npm packages with codepen you best use: "cdn.skypack.dev/package-name" (blog.codepen.io/2020/11/18/skypack-codepen)